# HTML5 offline mode and geolocation

Tags: web-applications, caching, html, geolocation

Is it possible to still use the geolocation features when you are in offline mode in HTML5?  It appears that when I am online (navigator.onLine = true), the geolocation works fine.  But when I go offline (navigator.onLine = false), I get thrown to my error callback and the error indicates geolocation not available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's going to depend on how the GeoLocation in that particular browser is wired up.  In Firefox, GeoLocation depends on [Google Location Services](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries#Geo.) which works by sending some network information to a web service - obviously this is not going to work when you're offline as the web service will not be available.

If you had a browser which communicated directly with GPS hardware then it would work offline, but I don't think you'll find any desktop browsers with that sort of integration - maybe some mobile ones will.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I had no idea that Google location services was involved for Firefox.  In my case, is mobile safari.  Do we know how that is wired up?

Comment: @HunterX3 I can't find any documentation either way, unfortunately.  I guess if it's not working for you then that indicates it's not using the GPS.

Comment: Geolocation currently doesn't work with Firefox (3.6.9) due to an internal JavaScript error on their part.

Comment: To make a long answer short if your device has GPS then your offline web application will work, otherwise it will not. This can be reference in the API "Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input."

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with @robertc. Navigator object does access geolocation from GPS in **mobile browsers.**

And for those who are looking for offline geolocation through mobile browser [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) cordova plugin might help.

> It is based on the [W3C Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

Which says:

> "This specification is limited to providing a scripting API for retrieving geographic position information associated with a **hosting device**."

I have implemented and it is working well even if you don't have: **active network**, it can fetch geolocation from **GPS**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an answer for you, but you might try setting a high maximumAge in the PositonOptions structure to see if it will give you an out of date one at least.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, and it didn't work.  I'm almost sure I had this working, maybe I had a flaw in my code that made it appear that it was working.  Hopefully someone will have an idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Today by August 3rth 2013, Offline Geolocation on browsers simply DO NOT WORK, after hundres of tests and PhoneGap + HTML5 tries. If anybody makes it work please tell us how....

Comment: Abraham, I feel your pain.  I had such high hopes for that too work.  Maybe we just have to wait a year or two.

Comment: You could try http://www.offlineGeolocation.com - It's for Android, and could be made to work with Phonegap by converting it into a Phonegap plugin.