# how capturing geolocation with device offline - cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation

I am developing an application using the cordova and found a need to take the data of latitude and longitude of the User, but my application will be used offline (without internet access).

I'm with two questions:

1 - How to check if the unit is active GPS or not?

2 - How I can get the latitude and longitude Offline without internet connection? It's possible?

Comment: you don't need internet tp get GPS datas

Comment: are you able to capture the location offline ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I´ll try to answer you:

1.- There you have the way to use [PhoneGap GeoLication API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) to check location, and if GPS is enabled. Check this too:  [Use PhoneGap to Check if GPS is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006454/use-phonegap-to-check-if-gps-is-enabled)

2.- Yes, the GPS is a satellite system that allows your device to track it´s current position on earth. It´s independent from your Cellphone operator, and then, from the Internet Connection.  Then, your device will be able to know it´s position. [HTML5 offline mode and geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693256/html5-offline-mode-and-geolocation)

In addition, you´ll probably need Internet connection to show a map. There are not much solutions for offline maps. Just artisan ones: http://davidrs.com/wp/phonegap-3-0-leaflet-offline-maps/

Hope it helps

**REMEMBER**: When turning on plane mode, most of devices will turn off GPS antenna too.

Comment: thanks for the tip.Regarding use the offline GPS, the procedure is the same for online to offline? or change anything in the way I capture the place?

Comment: You will get only lat and lng (sure will be the same way). Yo get placename, street and other data, you'll need an online service like google maps

Answer (score 1):

To check if the GPS is available or not you can use this [diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) - it works for Android and iOS. It can also be used to display the native location settings screen to allow the user to enable location services. For example:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("GPS is "+(enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled");
    if(!enabled){
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
    }
},function(error){
    console.error("An error occurred: "+ error);
});
```

As the other answer already states, you can receive a user's location using GPS without needing an internet connection using the geolocation API, but if you want to display a map you'll need a custom solution that doesn't rely on online maps such as Google.

If you want to record the user's location while offline, you can store this information offline in local persistent storage and upload it when the user has an internet connection again. You could use something like [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) for the storage.

Comment: thanks for the tip.Regarding use the offline GPS, the procedure is the same for online to offline? or change anything in the way I capture the place?

Comment: There's no change in the way you consume GPS positions, whether you are online or offline. You set up a watcher using `watchPosition()` and each time the OS receives a position update from GPS hardware, your handler function is called. If capturing user location is your objective, I would push each position into a persistent local queue then periodically dequeue and upload queue entries when online.

Comment: Got it... My idea is to give the option to the user the time he want to save the site, would equal a save point.

The purpose of my application is being used in the middle of a forest that does not have internet, and would collect some information from sites he visits, he would then export this data to the online application.

Comment: installed plugin in my project but this error occurred:
  Line 36: Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'diagnostic' of undefined

Comment: the plugin documentation is out of date - it should be `cordova.plugins` now, not `window.plugins` - I've updated my example - see [this issue thread](https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/1) for more.

Comment: FYI using GPS in a forest, you will at best get an inaccurate signal, if not no GPS signal. I have done a lot of field testing using smartphones under tree cover and the results are not good. You will need to build significant error tolerance into your app to cope with this. At least until [Galileo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_%28satellite_navigation%29) becomes available in the next couple of years - it promises much increased signal strength that will penetrate forests and buildings...

Comment: So my goal is that from the moment he is in a forest my application will understand that he has no connection to the internet. Regarding the change of window. for cordova. its working.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use geolocationOptions to controll if it use the hardware gps module:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

then when your phone is gps ready, you can get gps info without network access.

> enableHighAccuracy: Provides a hint that the application needs the
> best possible results. By default, the device attempts to retrieve a
> Position using network-based methods. Setting this property to true
> tells the framework to use more accurate methods, such as satellite
> positioning. (Boolean)