# GeoLocation API not working in offline mode

Tags: javascript, google-api, geolocation, offline

I am working on a application using Geolocation API.It working fine if i am connected to internet but in offline mode i am getting following error.
`"Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received."`

But according to this blog ([how capturing geolocation with device offline - cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713808/how-capturing-geolocation-with-device-offline-cordova/30714176)) Geolocation api works fine in offline mode also.

I am unable to understand the reason ,why it is not working in my case ?

Comment: It works if you don't have internet, but you still need the GPS on.

Comment: GPS is on. I am testing on safari browser.

Comment: Aaaah, Safari...  What about Chrome? :P

Comment: Not working. required to install PhoneGap or Cordova? I am using web application (React js +Pyhon).